# How do you install less css command line compiler?

Tags: ruby, css, npm

From my understanding and correct me if I'm wrong, I have to get ruby or NPM installed to get the less css compiler working.

I don't have any ruby installed and I'm not really sure how to get my computer to that point. I also want to minimize my footprint; installing the minimal amount of ruby libraries if possible (because i will never use ruby except for when i run less).

What are the steps involved in getting less working and running?

Before you down vote, I know there was [this previous thread](https://askubuntu.com/questions/51256/less-ccs-compiler-install) (Less CCS compiler install).

This particular person already has some other packages installed. I'm trying to figure out all the packages needed to get to that point.

Or if someone could point me to the right documentation I would be thrilled!

Comment: Also discovered this app: http://code.krml.fr/less.app it requires installing inotify-tools

Answer (score 40, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure if by compiler you want something that will automatically compile your less files on the fly or on the server.  Because otherwise you can

```
$ sudo apt-get install node-less yui-compressor
```

(On Ubuntu 12.04, the `node-less` package is called `node-less`.)

and then,

```
$ lessc example.less > compiled_example.css
$ yui-compressor -o small_and_compiled_example.css compiled_example.css
```

Comment: thanks this works in Ubuntu 13.04 too :) first day with LESS

Answer (score 8):

Most simple way is to install nodejs with its package manager npm. Nodejs is in the repositories, but that one is a bit outdated, instead you could use this ppa:

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:chris-lea/node.js
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nodejs
```

( https://github.com/joyent/node/wiki/Installing-Node.js-via-package-manager )
Especially if you're doing JavaScript/Web development nodejs is pretty important today.

At this point it's simply (as stated on http://lesscss.org)

```
npm install -g less
```

Probably, because you install globally (for the command), you need to prepend this comment with `sudo`.

Comment: Unfortunately, the version of Nodejs which is available through the Ubuntu repositories is incompatible with the version of LessCSS which you get with `npm install -g less` (at least as of July 2013).

Comment: I think that the `nodejs` package now contains the npm command so you don't need to (it caused an error for me) install it separately.

Answer (score 6):

First of all, there are a few things that need to be said:

- Ruby on Debian (and therefore by extension, Ubuntu) has a horrible setup with ruby.
- As such, the "recommended" solution is to compile and install your own version of ruby - this is made fairly painless with [`railsready`](https://github.com/joshfng/railsready).

> wget --no-check-certificate
>   https://raw.github.com/joshfng/railsready/master/railsready.sh && bash
>   railsready.sh

What that script will do for you is download ruby, compile it and then install it for you. After that, you need to run `exec $SHELL`, and then you can install less with  with `gem install less` (no need for sudo)

Comment: I've checked the less.js repository - it is 100% javascript, why do  I need rails to install it?

Comment: @Evgeny At the time I wrote this, it was still recommended that you use the ruby version of less.js. I'll update my answer with the new, "proper" instructions shortly.

Answer (score 3):

On Ubuntu 12.04, the LessCSS version in the repository is 1.2.2. To get LessCSS 1.3.3, you could use Node Package Manager :

```
sudo apt-get install npm
```

and then

```
npm install less
```

After that you'll have to change your PATH or use full path to the less compiler:

```
~/node_modules/less/bin/lessc
```

Comment: Change my PATH?

Comment: You can see where the node bin's are by using `$ npm bin` for local folder's binary links and `$ npm bin -g` for global node package binaries, respectively.

Answer (score 0):

There is also a `python-lesscpy` compiler, but it [doesn't work for Bootstrap 3](https://github.com/lesscpy/lesscpy/issues/22) at least.